# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter didn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to add Spring Security to my projcet, but it didnt work. I'm still can acess to my webapp without any login.

Main configuration

```
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

what i'm doing wrong? 
Using SpringSecurity 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

To enable Spring Security need to add class like this

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

or xml configuration

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```